# How do i loading dataset when running workflow in remote repo using a relative path when actual downloaded dataset is residing in a local repo?

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, github, github-actions, git-remote

I have a info.db file saved in a 'data' folder residing in my local repo.

I want to run a github-actions.yml workflow file (which calls a bash script that runs a .py file) in github-actions. The .py file makes a call to a relative path (e.g 'data/info.db') in my local repo, and load the database to perform some ML tasks. However, i do not wish to load the info.db file in my remote repo.

Would like to seek some advises on how this can be done.

Many thanks!

I tried to use the below codes in my python file but my workflow can only run if my info.db file is loaded in the remote repo:

```
import sqlite3 #For SQLite database
import sqlalchemy #For SQLite database

try:
    conn = sqlite3.connect("data/info.db")    
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

#Now in order to read in pandas dataframe we need to know table name (i.e. info)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';")

df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM info', conn)
conn.close()
```

Comment: Hi! Well, one thing is certain you need the SQLite3 DB file to use it. Your local repo cannot be accessed on GHA if you don't push it there or make it available somehow.

Comment: You can create DB on runtime and generate on GHA if that's a possibility. Otherwise, if you already have data in DB, you'll have to make it available during testing on GHA.

Comment: Thanks @Azeem for the response, yes i am using the SQLite3 DB file. Can you elaborate on "Create DB on runtime and generate on GHA"?

Comment: You can create a DB during runtime and use that. SQLite3 may already be installed on the runner that you're using. See the list of [preinstalled software](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#preinstalled-software). Also, include your workflow in your question. Thanks!